# Database Page Compression and ColumnStore Archive - is data compressed when in buffer pool and when sent to client?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, compression, columnstore

One of benefits of Page Compression or ColumnStore Archive is reduced storage space requirements
Here I have two questions:

1. When compressed data is read from disk to buffer pool, in the buffer pool it is stored in compressed form, too ?
   Does compression help to reduce memory (buffer pool) requirements as well ?
2. If answer to first question is "yes", then when compressed data is read from buffer pool by application over network, is it decompressed before sending to client ?
   Or it is sent over network in compressed form ?

Comment: @PaulWhite while part of the answers here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292116/test-to-see-when-table-is-candidate-for-compression-row-or-page "partially" answers my question, it mentions only Page compression; is behaviour the same for both Page and ColumnStore compression, or for ColumnStore it is different ? If different, can this question be reopened, what do you think ?

Comment: Yes it is the same (as far as your questions here are concerned) for both rowstore and columnstore.